# AWS SSL vs Comodo (or other)

Tags: ssl

Is there an advantage or reasons for choosing to use a paid SSL certificate from Comodo (or another) over using the new AWS Certificate Manager (free SSL certificates)?

I'm specifically talking about Domain Validated SSL (not Organizational or Extended Validation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well AWS free certificates can only be deployed either on an **ELB or aws cloudfront**. If you intend to use the certificate in either one of them then AWS certificates is the best option, other wise for any other **web server** you have to opt a paid SSL certificate, AWS certificate won't work their.